# file_get_contents or readfile for displaying filesystem image

Tags: php, function

Can anyone advise on what is the best PHP function for displaying an image stored in a filesystem - `file_get_contents` or `readfile`. We are switching from displaying images stored in the database so we still need to call the images through a PHP file and cannot link directly to the filesystem. I've seen people recommending both functions but I'm inclined towards using `readfile`. Would appreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you don't need to manipulate the images (resizing, adding watermarks,...) [`readfile()`](https://www.php.net/readfile) will be the best choice as it writes the file directly to the output buffer. [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will read the file into memory instead - requiring a lot of memory with large files.

Comment: Stefan, what if the files are very small (40 kb) but too many ? Still file_get_contents() better choice ?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 9):

Be sure to take **caching** into account when writing scripts like this!

A webserver serving a static image will do negotiation with the client when the image is re-requested on the next page visit, and if the server determines that the cached copy of the image at the client side is still valid, the image will not be retransmitted.

Since the naive script does not do this negotiation, the image will be retransmitted to the client on every page request, costing you a lot more bandwidth than necessary.

There are three mechanisms for this. I can't tell you exactly how to write the optimal script, as I've never had to do this before and I'm not sure how the different caching headers interoperate and on what HTTP version, but I encourage you to research into this further.

The three mechanisms that I know of:

**Expires** (HTTP/1.0)

The simplest one. This header tells the client that the image will definitely be valid until the given moment in time. The client will not even do a request to the script until this time has passed, so setting this appropriately can save you (some) CPU cycles on the server and image loading latency in your web app.

How you should set this depends entirely on your application; are your images changing rapidly or rarely? If the image changes before the Expires time you've sent to the client, the client will not see the new image.

Example:

```
header("Expires: " . gmdate('D, d-M-Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 60)); // Valid for a minute
```

(Note: Expires seems to have been superseded by **Cache-Control** in HTTP/1.1)

**If-Modified-Since** (HTTP/1.1)

An HTTP/1.1 client can send this header if it already has a copy of the image, and notes what time the copy dates from. You can then determine in your database if the current version of the image was changed at an earlier or later time. If the version of the client is still the right one, simply send a "304 Not Modified" response and quit (thereby preventing having to transfer the image).

Example:

```
$cache_time   = parse_browsers_date_time_format($_SERVER["IF-MODIFIED-SINCE"]);
$actual_time  = get_current_resource_time_from_db();

if ($actual_time <= $cache_time) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
    die;
}

// ... Produce and output resource here
```

(Note: clients may only actually send the **If-Modified-Since** if you also send **Last-Modified** in the original response. I'm not sure about that, research for yourself.)

**ETag/If-None-Match** (HTTP/1.1)

This method is similar to the **If-Modified-Since** negotiation, but instead of times it uses a hash of the image as to see if the content has changed. It works as follows: the server calculates some hash for the image, and sends this hash the first time the image is requested in the **ETag** header.

On subsequent requests, the server will send the hash back in the request field **If-None-Match**. If the hash of the client is the same as the current hash of the image, the image was not changed in between and the script can suffice by simply sending "304 Not Modified".

Since ETags seem to be actually intended to be used to prevent concurrency issues in client requests with side effects (i.e., POST and PUT), and because calculating a hash is a costly operation, I think the If-Modified-Since approach will be a better fit for most file-serving applications.

Comment: we've been looking into this today, thanks for all the ideas.

Comment: For the last few hours I kept trying to specify expiration headers in my php script that outputs an image, it finally solved it by `header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");` I don't fully understand the implications of forcing `Not Modified` but image loads faster on next load so it must work.

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile('something.jpg');
```

[readfile()](http://www.php.net/readfile) seems more useful for this purpose as it reads a file and writes it to the output buffer returning the number of bytes read from the file, or false on an error.

Comment: fpassthru does the same with fopen's file handler.

Answer (score 0):

I should use [fpassthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php)
Using fopen you can handle errors more precisely.

PS: be sure, that your direct output from filesystem is not vulnerable!

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents()` is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance. But that aside, I don't know what is better. You could try to see if a huge file give better performance with `file_get_contents()`, but I expect the network traffic is a much bigger concern than the servers file-IO. and `readfile()` is used to download the file by passing the `content-type` in `header()`.