# PHP readfile vs. file_get_contents

Tags: php, function, filesystems, readfile

I have used following code to generate zip

```
// push to download the zip
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
readfile($zip_name);
```

this code works fine but for unknown reasons was not working until I tried

```
// push to download the zip
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
echo file_get_contents($zip_name);
```

I am curious about finding what is happening in both the cases

Comment: You meant `file_get_contents` right?

Comment: What does "not working" means? Have you tried setting error reporting to the appropriate value and read any error / warning messages?

Comment: yes I did so and it was showing a blank page with single \n

Comment: @Shankar yes file_get_contents worked the first time and so on

Comment: possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents or readfile for displaying filesystyem image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909672/file-get-contents-or-readfile-for-displaying-filesystyem-image)

Comment: My observation is that readfile was trying to throw file while it was generating, but file_get_contents wait till it get genrated successfully.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Readfile will read the file directly into the output buffer, and file_get_contents will load the file into memory, when you echo the result the data is copied from memory to the output buffer effectively using 2 times the memory of readfile.

Comment: Yes this is what my observation is that readfile was trying to throw file while it was generating, but file_get_contents wait till it get genrated successfully.