# Adding and styling external file

Tags: php, html, css, iframe

There is a file on another site that I do not own, with a URL in the following format:

```
http://example.com/path/with/some/variables
```

I want to include this file in one of my own pages. I could use `iframe` to do this, but I also want to change the CSS of something within the included file. To my knowledge, I can't do this with this method.

However, I can't seem to be able to successfully add this via PHP either, with something like:

```
<?php include 'http://example.com/path/with/some/variables'; ?>
```

I'm not sure what other methods exist that can do this, but surely this must be possible.

Also, I'm aware of the security implications of using `include` in a situation like this.

Comment: Do you want to just dump the content of external url inside your page?

Comment: What is that file? A piece of HTML? Just a CSS file ? Something else ?

Comment: Correct. It's got HTML, CSS, and some JS within it. Basically, whatever you would see in the source of the page is what I'm trying to display.

Comment: If you access a PHP script through HTTP, it runs the script and returns the output, it doesn't copy the PHP source.

Comment: Then use `file_get_content($url);` to get the all content as string and dump it wherever you want [http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php]

Comment: What's the difference between that function, and the readfile one that Barmar posted?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095175/php-readfile-vs-file-get-contents this is the difference

Comment: Hah, I just finished reading that exact page! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `readfile`:

```
<?php readfile('http://example.com/path/with/some/variables'); ?>
```

Comment: This won't let you change the style of the included file.

Comment: Sure it will. The included file will be merged into the current output, and any CSS you load locally will apply to it.

Comment: @Barmar You can't style the content of an iframe from the including page if it's cross-domain.

Comment: There's no iframe. That's what he's trying to replace with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, security limitations won't allow you do do this directly in an iframe, by manipulating the DOM of the iframed file.

To do it in PHP, you could create a PHP script to read the contents of the URL and add an external CSS file that you've created, to override whatever you want.  So:

**myreader.php:**

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://example.com/path/with/some/variables");
$contents = preg_replace("/<head>/", "<head>\n<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='mystyle.css'>", $contents, 1);

echo $contents;
```

**and then create mystyle.css:**

```
body {
  color : red !important;
}
```

Finally, either just point your browser to myreader.php, or if you still want it in an iframe, point the iframe src to myreader.php.

PS:  Stealing is wrong  :)

Comment: Don't worry, it's not stealing. It's a publicly available resource that is normally meant to be used via iframes. I just wanted to make a slight edit to the styling. Either way, if I already have a CSS file on the page this is meant to be displayed in, I can simply add the relevant styles there, right?

Comment: I was just kidding  :)  I don't think you can style an iframe's contents from the page including the iframe.  Though, you can style the iframe (i.e. its border, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `file_get_contents`

```
<?php $content = file_get_contents('http://example.com/path/with/some/variables'); ?>
```

Here is the documentation [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: Its file_get_contents

Comment: @Javad Consider updating your answer.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel I did it; I don't know how come I typed "-"; anyway thanks