# PHP display image without HTML

Tags: php, image

How may I display an image without using any kind of HTML.

Let's say I have some protected images, which may only be shown to some users.
The protected image is in directory images/protected/NoOneCanViewMeDirectly.png

Then we have a PHP file in the directory images/ShowImage.php, which check if the user is permitted to view the image.

How may I display the image using PHP only.

If you're not sure what I mean this is how I want to display the image. http://gyazo.com/077e14bc824f5c8764dbb061a7ead058

The solution is not `echo '<img src="images/protected/NoOneCanViewMeDirectly.png">';`

Comment: `<img src="file.php">` and use a header.

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: @EngineerCoder It is, just not in the typical syntax

Comment: How exactly isn't this a question? "How may I display the image using PHP only."

Comment: @Kaare Actually, this question's been asked before. You just needed to Google your question's title. You've not shown us what you tried. You only mention/asked "how".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just header out the image with the following syntax

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo file_get_contents(__DIR__."/images/protected/NoOneCanViewMeDirectly.png");
```

Comment: 1) Content type should be `image/png` for png files 2) better use `readfile(...)`

Comment: Thank you. That was what I searched for.

Comment: `image/jpg` and `.png`?

Comment: I didn't noticed the `png`, edited it into the answer. Never worked with readfile, so I don't know if it's better or not, but it works for me

Comment: also `__DIR__` will return you current location of script file, not root directory, so if you have this code in say `/modules/images/functions.php` your image path will be `/modules/images/iamges/protected/...`

Comment: @vladkras according to the question there's no other path where the script lies in. But in theory you're right

Answer (score 2):

```
if (<here your logic to show file or not>)
    $path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].<path_to_your_file>; // to get it correctly
    $ext = explode(".", $path);
    header("Content-Type: image/".array_pop($ext)); // correct MIME-type
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path)); // content length for most software
    readfile($path); // send it
}
```

Note: 1. `image/jpg` is not correct MIME-type, use `image/jpeg` instead (additional check needed), 2. `readlfile()` [is better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20095276/1713660) than `echo file_get_contents()` for binary data, 3. always try [to provide content length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) for browsers and other software

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`imagepng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) to output png image to browser:

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng("images/protected/NoOneCanViewMeDirectly.png");

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```