# PHP header 'audio/mpeg' performance issue

Tags: javascript, php, mp3, html5-audio

Ok, i have to build a secure music player; one that don't display music's source (even on the console).
I've **already built the logic**, but, in order to do that, my only way out was to use php header to strem mp3.

My question: is my performance loss "tolerable" doing **that**:

/main.js

```
Player.src = "music.php"
```

/music.php

```
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-length: ' . filesize($track));
header('Content-Disposition: filename="sometrack.mp3"');
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
print file_get_contents($track);
```

instead of **that**?:

/main.js

```
Player.src = "music.mp3"
```

By "tolerable", i mean: 10% loss? 15% loss?

Or Anyone has another suggestion?

Here is the github with the **very(!)** raw logic: https://github.com/filipemerker/securePlayer

Comment: `even on the console` Wrong.  It is fundamentally impossible to prevent the user from seeing the content in the Network tab.  Give up.

Comment: man, i built a token logic that allows me to, yes, show music.php on console, but if you access music.php without the correct token, you will see an error message. (take a look at the github) My question here is about performance not logic @SLaks

Comment: "is the performance tolerable" sounds a bit subjective.  What tests have you performed so far, and what is the actual, measurable performance difference (if any)?

Comment: that is a good observation. Latter i'll edit the question with my test screenshot. @user700390

Comment: @FilipeMerker: All the user needs to do is copy the existing response, or replay the request with the original cookie. (Which Chrome conveniently offers a context menu item to do)

Comment: @SLaks: boy, if you read the github files, you'll see that possessing the SAME cookie that played the music once, is useless. Every access asks for a new cookie which is generated at the very moment of the client-side request. Again: my logic is already built and tested (not a noob). Any **performance** tip?

Comment: @FilipeMerker: You're still wrong.  The user can easily replay the original cookie, since you don't have persistent state on the server.  If you do add persistent state, the user can just load the page without JS to get a new valid token.  **You can't do this**.

Comment: @SLaks: You even have the Flash fallback option, which is widelly used, for example, by extinct Grooveshark and the actual Spotify. If you say that is `fundamentally impossible  to prevent the user from seeing the content in the Network tab` that shows you are not aware of the possibilities. (:

Comment: @SLaks: Sorry for that, my mistake. The token is generated by server and emmited by client. Every token validation generates a new token. But my logic increases more complexity that makes really hard to hack it. Again, i'm not asking about my logic. I'm asking about php header streaming performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to do it that way, you should consider using *readfile* instead of file_get_contents

Take a look at [PHP readfile vs. file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095175/php-readfile-vs-file-get-contents).

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look (not a back-end developer here, any suggestions like that will help a lot :P )