# unable to display pdf file that is loaded from a external url in the chrome using php

Tags: php

The url will load the pdf document

```
https://riverside.iqm2.com/sameer/FileOpen.aspx?Type=14&ID=2157&Inline=True
but when i pass this url into
header() chrome is throwing the following error failed to load pdf document
```

.

```
$filename = 'https://riverside.iqm2.com/sameer/FileOpen.aspx?Type=14&ID=2157&Inline=True';
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Description:inline;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary');
header('Accept-range:bytes');
@readfile($filename);
```

i expect to download the pdf but the output is failed to load pdf document

Comment: the url you use probably use some internal process to provide actual url for the pdf, while in your php, it looks for the direct link

Comment: how to can implement the internal process using php

Comment: This does not appear to have anything whatsoever to do with `xpath` - please tag responsibly, not just “whatever”.

Comment: The error mentioned in comments, _“Object reference not set to an instance of an object.”_ does not appear to be a PHP error message to begin with - but the actual response you are getting from that remote site. So it is probably missing some “input” - could be something trivial like a proper User-Agent header send with the request.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer: [PHP readfile vs. file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095175/php-readfile-vs-file-get-contents)

Also as of [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) manual:

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen
>   wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to
>   specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for
>   links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have,
>   notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they
>   may provide.