# Fixing error with file_get_contents permission denied

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a question connected with JSON and PHP.  So, if you visit this site: http://air.moepp.gov.mk/graphs/site/pages/MakeGraph.php?station=SkopjeRegion&parameter=PM10D&beginDate=2018-02-10&beginTime=19:00&endDate=2018-02-17&endTime=19:00&i=1518893212453&lang=en

As a return you get HTML, but if you go to the response, the response is pure JSON, so I'm trying to get the JSON data, but I fail. Probably I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what. I tried with `file_get_contents()` and `curl` but I don't get anything from it... So here is what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://air.moepp.gov.mk/graphs/site/pages/MakeGraph.php?station=SkopjeRegion&parameter=PM10D&beginDate=2018-02-10&beginTime=12:00&endDate=2018-02-17&endTime=12:00&i=1518865590001&lang=en');  
$contents = json_decode($content, true);  
var_dump($contents);
```

And as return I get `NULL`.

Edit:

I figured out that my PHP function `file_get_contents()` is not properly working because of the problem with the permission. The problem was:

`file_get_contents('url'): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/xxx.php on line X`

After googling, and suggestion from @geoidesic, I found out that SELinux (Security Enhanced Linux) is blocking Apache (by default network connection from httpd (Apache) is disabled. So i followed step-by-step tutorial on http://drib.tech/programming/php-file_get_contents-not-working and finally got it to work. Anyways, here is the solution in short if someone needs it:

1. Be sure you have `allow_url_fopen=On` in your php.ini file. (If someone doesn't know where your php.ini file is, quick check with phpinfo() could get you everything.
2. Check status of SELinux:

   `sudo sestatus`

   If the status is **enabled** , then you can check whether the boolean flags **httpd_can_network_connect** and **httpd_unified** are enabled, set to 1:

   `sudo sestatus -b | grep httpd_can_network_connect` and `sudo sestatus -b | grep httpd_unified`

   If they're off, run this command to set them on:

   `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1 sudo setsebool -P httpd_unified 1`

   And then reboot, or restart httpd. So that's all, again, thanks a lot to the guy/s at [drib.tech](http://drib.tech).

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: If I go there I get JSON, what is `echo $content;`?

Comment: `curl` works fine here: `curl http://air.moepp.gov.mk/graphs/site/pages/MakeGraph.php\?station\=SkopjeRegion\&parameter\=PM10D\&beginDate\=2018-02-10\&beginTime\=19:00\&endDate\=2018-02-17\&endTime\=19:00\&i\=1518893212453\&lang\=en
{"measurements":[{"name":"Centar","data":[70.9839,15.8154,53.9789,74.6637,37.3094,38.0791,53.7531,null]},{"name":"GaziBaba","data":`... shortened for comment length limit.

Comment: Also `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: `echo $content` returns nothing (i guess i cannot echo that), and `curl` works for me too as well, but i don't know why it's returning null...

Comment: So, even the suggestion from @geoidesic with google doesn't work, and the return from error reporting is : `Warning: file_get_contents(http://air.moepp.gov.mk/graphs/site/pages/MakeGraph.php?station=SkopjeRegion&parameter=PM10D&beginDate=2018-02-10&beginTime=12:00&endDate=2018-02-17&endTime=12:00&i=1518865590001&lang=en): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/json-return.php on line 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your PHP error log. Possibly you have a network issue where your PHP instance can't access that URL. Perhaps you're running it from a virtual environment that doesn't have external network access for example.

Try `file_get_contents('google.com')` for example and see what you get back.

I tried your code and it worked perfectly for me. I got JSON back.

I don't know why you say "If you visit this site... you get HTML" because you don't, you get JSON.

Comment: error log is empty, I'm running Apache on Fedora 27, everything works as it should except this...

Comment: What's not working? Do you mean you can't curl google? If not then you probably also can't curl the URL you've been trying. You should be telling us more about the environment because as I said in the answer this is probably a network issue.

Comment: So, I can curl google and my url, but in PHP it's not working, and PHP return error : `Warning: file_get_contents(http://air.moepp.gov.mk/graphs/site/pages/MakeGraph.php?station=SkopjeRegion&parameter=PM10D&beginDate=2018-02-10&beginTime=12:00&endDate=2018-02-17&endTime=12:00&i=1518865590001&lang=en): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/json-return.php on line 6` . I have all permission on the file

Comment: When you say "I can curl google and my URL" – I assume you mean on the command line. But what I meant was try curl google in your PHP file.

Comment: Like I said it's a networking issue. If I disconnect my WiFi and then run the script I also get `null` as a return. You are probably working on a virtualised environment like vagrant or virtualbox where the server cannot access the network. Or you have an SELINUX or firewall issue which is blocking HTTP traffic for the apache group or user or similar.

Comment: Could you help me with figuring out whats blocking HTTP traffic on Apache ? And yes I meant curl via command line...

Comment: Do `tail -f /var/log/secure` this may give you some information. However this is a different question you are asking now. I suggest you do some research first and then ask a new question. If the answer to this one satisfies you (i.e. it's a network issue) then you should accept it.

Comment: I tried it now on Windows 7, works like a charm :D
So I will do some research for now on this... Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue just now and it was caused by selinux.

Resolved by running:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
sudo setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer for me
Apache Server SELinux Boolean List this was set to off

```
httpd_can_network_connect --> off
```

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-managing_confined_services-the_apache_http_server-booleans

Answer (score -1):

Use `$content = readfile('url');` and there should be no errors.

I was having this problem too but that worked, and also [readfile is faster than file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/909699/8804293).

Comment: [`Readfile`](https://www.php.net/readfile) doesn't **return** file contents. It echoes the content and returns number of bytes read. Quite a difference. Your answer is wrong.