# XML data works well on local machine but do not work online

Tags: php, ajax, xml

I have code like this:

```
$ares_ico_fin = "";
$ares_dic_fin = "";
$ares_firma_fin = "";
$ares_ulice_fin = "";
$ares_cp1_fin   = "";
$ares_cp2_fin   = "";
$ares_mesto_fin = "";
$ares_psc_fin   = "";
$ares_stav_fin = "";


$file = @file_get_contents("http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_bas.cgi?ico=".$_POST["ico_ajax_send"]);

if($file)
  {
    $xml = @simplexml_load_string($file);
  }



if($xml) 
  {
    $ns = $xml->getDocNamespaces();
    $data = $xml->children($ns['are']);
    $el = $data->children($ns['D'])->VBAS;
    
    if (strval($el->ICO) == $_POST["ico_ajax_send"]) 
      {
        $ares_ico_fin = strval($el->ICO);
        $ares_dic_fin = strval($el->DIC);
        $ares_firma_fin = strval($el->OF);
        $ares_ulice_fin = strval($el->AA->NU);
        $ares_cp1_fin   = strval($el->AA->CD);
        $ares_cp2_fin   = strval($el->AA->CO);
        if($ares_cp2_fin != ""){ $ares_cp_fin = $ares_cp1_fin."/".$ares_cp2_fin; }else{ $ares_cp_fin = $ares_cp1_fin; }
        $ares_mesto_fin = strval($el->AA->N);
        $ares_psc_fin   = strval($el->AA->PSC);
        $ares_stav_fin = 1;
      }
```

It works fine on my local machine, but I do not get any data if tries it on remoteserver...

I read help like: [Fixing error with file_get_contents permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48845039/fixing-error-with-file-get-contents-permission-denied)

with no success, thanks for ideas how to solve it, have a nice day subii

Comment: Have you identified how far it gets through the code when the data goes missing?

Comment: I would start by removing the `@` [error control operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) so you don't hide any warnings from trying to access the remote file or parsing it as XML. Both can go wrong, and because of the `@` you won't see that.